# Spark withWatermark, only store values before and after a gap

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I've got data comming in over Kafka to a Spark Structured Streaming application. To simplify, each message on kafka contains a device-id, a datetime and a value. The purpose of the streaming application is to calculate the difference between all values for each device.

I.e. if the input is

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:15 | 21 |

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:16 | 24 |

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:17 | 26 |

I would like the output to be

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:16 | 3 |
| 1 | 20210922-15:17 | 2 |

To solve this, and to handle that messages can come in late (up to 10 days) I'm using `withWatermark` on the `Dateteime`-column, with 10 days. However this leads to a huge memory usage if I have many devices since spark will store all the values for 10 days for all devices in memory.

In practice however, I do not have the need to store e.g., the value for 15:16 for Device X, if I already have retreived the values for 15:15 and 15:17.

So, instead of storing something like this in memory (due to `withWatermark`)

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:15 |  |
| 1 | 20210922-15:16 |  |
| 1 | 20210922-15:17 |  |
| 1 | 20210922-15:18 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:15 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:16 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:17 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:18 |  |

I would only need this

| Device-ID | Datetime | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210922-15:15 |  |
| 1 | 20210922-15:18 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:15 |  |
| 2 | 20210922-14:18 |  |

Is this doable?

Comment: In practice however, I do not have the need to store e.g., the value for 15:16 for Device X, if I already have retreived the values for 15:15 and 15:17.

 -- Can you elaborate a little more on this

Comment: @ChitralVerma I only need "old" values to be able to calculate diffs when new values arrive. So if i get value with eventtime 15:17, I will need the value for 15:16 to be able to calculate the diff. But if i've retreived the value for 15:17, I'm no longer in need for 15:16 anymore after using it.